# Separate 'networks' in a panda's dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following df:

```
 first  second
0     a       3
1     b       5
2     a       2
3     e       9
4     c       2
5     d       7
6     d       8
7     c       5
```

I would like to separate the distinct 'networks' into their own dataframes.  So e.g. a goes to 2, but 2 is also linked to c, which is also linked to 5, etc. meaning they form a network.

This means you should end up with the following three dataframes:

```
 first  second
0     a       3
1     b       5
2     a       2
3     c       5
4     c       2

  first  second
0     d       7
1     d       8

  first  second
0     e       9
```

Is there an easy way to do this, and is there a way to generalise to any number of columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html) from `networkx` to subset the dataframe

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'first', 'second')
[df.query('first in @cc') for cc in nx.connected_components(G)]
```

---

```
[  first  second
 0     a       3
 1     b       5
 2     a       2
 4     c       2
 7     c       5,
   first  second
 3     e       9,
   first  second
 5     d       7
 6     d       8]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Does this also work if you have more than two columns?

Comment: If you want to check for the relation between three or more columns, then we need to construct the `networkx` graph in a slightly different manner. You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389570/build-networkx-directed-graph-or-flow-chart-from-more-than-one-column-of-pandas) for the construction of `networkx` graph when you have three or more columns.